# Image Catalog with ASP.NET MVC and dialog control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

end development being a back-end for several projects 
Now I'm developping a web application in ASP.NEt MVC 3

I have a form which contains some fields and the possibility to upload an image which has been working perfectly

I would like now to give the user the possibility to select an image from a catalog so i decided to use a dialog once a button clicked and select an image , I have been able to show the dialog with some images but couldn't find how to select an image and bind it to my viewmodel

Here is the code I'm having right now

```
 public class PopupController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ProductPartial()
    {
        ViewBag.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images_upload"))
                          .Select(fn => "~/images_upload/" + Path.GetFileName(fn));
        return PartialView("_ProductPartial");
    }
}
```

and the views

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: screen.width/2,
        height:screen.height/2,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Product',
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("ProductPartial", "Popup")");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
     $("#opener").click(function () {
         $("#dialog").dialog("open");
     });
 });
```

and finally the partial view

```
@foreach(var image in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Images)
{
<img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" width="100" height="100" />
}
```

My viewModel contains this property

```
public HttpPostedFileBase imageVente { get; set; }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're showing a list of server-side images and allowing the user to select one.

For this, you don't need HttpPostFileBase which allows the user to upload a *new* image from their PC.

Add the filename to the image tag:

```
@foreach(var image in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Images)
{
    <img data-name='image' src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" width="100" height="100" class='selectable-image' />
}
```

add a hidden field to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedImage" id="selectedImage" />
```

add an onclick to the images to add 'selected' class and populate the hidden field

```
$(".selectable-image").click(function() 
{
    $(".selectable-image").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("#selectedImage").val($(this).data("name"))
});
```

in your controller action / viewmodel, retrieve the `selectedImage` name:

```
public string selectedImage { get; set; }
```

---

**Edit**: The above is from the original question which displays some images from the server.  This allows the user to select an image and pass that back to the server.

Additional comment clarifies that the HttpPostFileBase wasn't a mistake and requirement is to also allow client side upload.

In which case, simply add an `input type='file'` to your form with name matching your parameter:

```
<input type='file' name="imageVente">
```

I'm not 100% sure you can use this as a model property, but it does work as a parameter on the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase imageVente)
```

Make sure your `form` also has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  (check numerous SO questions for more details on uploading files).

Comment: Thanks for the answer it looks legit , I'm using the two options in fact , server-side images and user upload , do I need an other property for this ? now I'm converting the HttpPostFileBase to bytes before saving it to my Database